# Characterizing von Neumann regularity

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be  a commutative unital ring. I want to show the following equivalences:

(1) $R$ is zero-dimensional and reduced,

(2) every ideal in $R$ is radical,

(3)  $R$ is von Neumann regular.

See wikipedia for the definitions. The only step I am missing is  (1) to (2).  I only see that the zero ideal (0) is radical.  Any idea would be welcome. Or a reference to a textbook containing this proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) <-> (3) is pretty much trivial.  The key observations are that $x^2R$ being radical implies that $x$ is a Von Neumann Regular (VNR) element, and that $x$ being a VNR element implies that $x^n$ divides $x$.

So if you're good with (3) -> (1), we might as well just show (1) -> (3) directly.

For good measure we'll do it two ways.

**First Way**: (This is the way I've seen most often).  We start by considering the module $xR / x^2R$.  If we can show that this is the zero module, then we'll have $xR = x^2R$ — end of proof.  Being zero is a local property, so in fact we only need to show that $(xR / x^2R)_\mathfrak{m} = 0$ for each maximal ideal of $R$.  Since localization distributes over quotients, we're actually looking at $xR_\mathfrak{m}/x^2R_\mathfrak{m}$. By assumption that $R$ is $0$-dimensional and reduced, $R_\mathfrak{m}$ is a field.  Hence the image of $x$ in $R_\mathfrak{m}$ is either $0$ or a unit.  In either case, certainly $xR_\mathfrak{m}/x^2R_\mathfrak{m} = 0$.

**Second Way**: Note that $x \in R$ is a VNR element iff $xR$ is a direct summand of $R$.  Indeed, if $xR$ is a direct summand of $R$, then $xR + J = R$ with $xR \cap J = 0$, so we can write $xa + j = 1$ for some $a \in R, j \in J$.  Then $xj = 0$ and $x^2a = x$ follows.  Conversely, if $x^2a = x$, then $axR = xR$ and $ax$ is an idempotent.  When $e \in R$ is an idempotent, one always has $eR \oplus (1-e)R = R$.

With this in mind, our approach will be to show that $xR \oplus Ann(x) = R$ for any element $x$ of a reduced $0$-dimensional ring.  First check that $xR \cap Ann(x) = 0$ because $R$ is reduced (indeed this characterizes reduced rings).  Then note $xR + Ann(x)$ is never contained in a minimal prime of a reduced ring, as $PR_P = 0$.  Since $R$ is assumed to be $0$-dimensional, moreover $xR + Ann(x)$ is not contained in any prime ideal, and must be the entire ring.

Comment: Could one prove the assertion that $xR+Ann(x)$ is not contained in a minimal prime without using localisations? (I am  not yet  familiar with this power tool in algebra; I am an analyst).

Comment: I think one can proceed as follows: use that the Krull dimension of $R$ is $0$
if and only if  for all $a\in R$ there is $y\in R$ and $n\in \N$ such that
$a^n(1+ay)=0$. Since $aR\cap Ann(a)=0$ we get that $n=1$.